# Search field with objectID inside an array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of objectid stored inside a field called `linkedAccounts` like this:

```
linkedAccount : [
  {accountId:639f131640e86ede985400aa, comments:[]}, 
  {accountId:639f131qwqwqe86ede985400aa, comments:[]}, 
  {accountId:639f131640e86ede985400aa, comments:[]}
]
```

when I do `console.log` of `accountId`, I get:

```
new ObjectId("639f131640e86ede985400aa").
```

I want to find a specific object inside `linkedAccount` that matches with `req.params.accountId`

I wrote this line but it's not working. Here review is a specific document inside which I have `linkedAccount`.

```
review.linkedAccount.find((c) => c.accountId === (new ObjectId(req.params.accountId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$` projection, which will return a matching object in array,

```
let r = review.find({
  "linkedAccount.accountId": ObjectId(req.params.accountId)
},
{
  "linkedAccount.$": 1
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XDpp8TUZqBs)

Comment: I'm getting an error:  review.find is not a function. I tried review.linkedAccount.find that is not working as well.

Comment: you need to provide more details, like how you declared review?